# Function to return True if integer k and n in list?

Tags: python, list

Very new to python... If I give a list that has two integers n and k, the function should return Boolean True. K has to be in the list the number of n times. For example, if I call matchingValues([1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1], 1, 4) should return True since 1 is in the list 4 times. I'm guessing I have to use the .count() option but not sure how to write it... Wish I could give more code but unfortunately I am very lost

```
    def matchingValues(aList,n,k):
```

Comment: Does 5 1's return False?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is define a variable which counts how many times n is in the list

```
found = 0
```

and then, iterate over your list with a loop

```
for x in range(0, len(aList)):
    if aList[x] == n:
        found += 1
return(found == k)
```

This is, however, if you want to avoid using the `count` function:

```
return(aList.count(n)==k)
```

Using the manual, hand-written loop will allow you to exit the loop as soon as you know there are `k` `n`s in the list, if you want the loop to work like that (however, I have not provided that code. I have only written exactly what `count` does)

If you want there to be AT LEAST `k` `n`s in `aList`, this would work for you

```
found = 0
for x in range(0, len(aList)):
    if aList[x] == n:
        found += 1
        if found == k:
            return True
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than a solution involving `len()` is to use the `.count()` method for lists. It takes an argument, and returns the number of times that argument appears in the list that it is called on.

Comment: Technically, an explicit loop with early out is better if `aList` might be huge, and the count satisfied early on; `.count` would finish counting even if the first `k` entries of `aList` were `n`. Admittedly, in the typical case, `count` is simpler and faster, pushing more work to the interpreter, which can do it faster than hand-written loops. Edit: On rereading OP, might want exactly `k`, not at least `k`, so maybe no short-circuiting?

Comment: True. Depends on how big you expect `aList` to be.

Comment: You can short cut when you've seen k+1: return False but can't shortcut a True.